# Holomorphic function is zero on an analytic set then $df=0$.

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

Assume we have an homomorphic function $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{C} $ which is holomorphic on the open set $U$ of $\mathbb{C}^n$. Assume there is $V\subset U$ analytic and that $f$ restricted to $V$ equals zero ($V$ is obviously not open in $U$).
Is it true that this implies that $df=0$? Here $d= \partial +\bar{\partial}$. If so, I need a hint on how to prove it. Or a reference.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean $f$ restricted to $V$? What do you mean $V \subset U$ analytic?  As written, the answer to your question is $f = 0 \implies df = 0$, which is not what I think you are going for...

Comment: I really meant $f$ restricted to $V$… sorry. Already edited.

Comment: What does $V$ analytic mean?  Could $V$ be a single point?  A whole subvariety?  You do realize that $df = 0$ iff $f$ is a constant right?

Comment: You may think of an analytic set as it's defined in here http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_variety . Also, $df=0$ implying $f$ constant would be true only if $V$ is open, which is not

Comment: So $f = 0$ on $V$, and you are asking whether this implies $df = 0$ on $V$?  The answer is no.  It is true that $df = 0$ when restricted to the tangent space of $V$, but in the normal directions we should not expect $df = 0$.  This is really just multivariable calculus, there is nothing special about complex analysis here.

Comment: Can you give me a counterexample? Things are a lot different in the holomorphic world

Comment: Also. It might bot be entirely clear that $d$ refers to the exterior differentiation. That is, $df$ is an 1-form

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20398/discussion-between-steven-gubkin-and-marra).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $V = \{(0,z):z \in \mathbb{C}\} \subset \mathbb{C}^2$, then $V$ is a complex analytic submanifold of $\mathbb{C}^2$.

The function $f(z_1,z_2) = z_1$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}^2$, and vanishes on $V$.  Nevertheless, $df = dz_1$, which is nonzero everwhere, even on $V$.  So the "theorem" in the question is false.

It is true that $df$ vanishes when restricted to the tangent space of $V$.  Maybe this is what you were thinking?

A related computation is that $d(fg) = fdg+gdf$, so if $f$ and $g$ both vanish on $V$, we would have $d(fg)$ vanishing on $V$.